# Getting "Can't Play this Video" message in some devices only

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-videoview

I have placed a video in `res` folder, So the location of this video is `res/splash_video.mp4`. I am playing this video at the Launch of Application like this.

```
String uriPath= "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+R.raw.splash_video;
Uri uri= Uri.parse(uriPath);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

This video is working perfectly fine in most of the devices, but in some it displays `Can't  play this video` message.

In `Android OS 5.1 (Samsung s4)`, it display error message, while in Android OS `5.1 Huawei`, its playing the video. Video is also working fine on `Samsung s5`, and `samsung s7`. In `Note 3` it can't play this video.

Are there any different folders per devices? or do i need to place the video in some other folder, or change the format of video?

Kindly guide me how to play video on each and every device.

Answer (score 0):

Use following ViewView Code:

```
VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
setContentView(videoHolder);
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);
videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        jumpMain();
    }
});
videoHolder.start();
videoHolder.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ((VideoView) v).stopPlayback();
        jumpMain();
        return true;
    }
});
```

for full tutorial, refer: 
http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/06/how-to-play-video-from-resources.html